# How to get class attributes without evaling it?

Tags: python, class, attributes, eval

For example, I have string (not loaded code):

```
class InfoClass:
    INFO = "Required info"
    
    def __init__(self):
        # Unsafe code, which can be executed
```

Is there any way to get INFO from InfoClass, without regex, while not executing **init** or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: use ast.parse
https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse

```
import ast

code = """
class InfoClass:
    INFO = "Required info"
"""

ast.parse(code).body[0].body[0].value.value
```

Output: Required info

Answer (score 1):

```
InfoClass.INFO # returns value.
```

Comment: The other code may have insecure (malware) inside of it. I can't just eval it

Comment: Try and write the attribute value in a file through python